# PHP JSON Sorting Issue

Tags: php, json

i have json decoded data. which is already stored in database.
Here is the data.!

```
{"sortlist":"block[]=D5e35a3db27fb4&block[]=K5e35a3f027fb5&block[]=C5e35a3f127fb6&block[]=F5e35a3fc27fb7&block[]=G5e35a40327fb9&block[]=H5e35a40c27fba","save_cont_flag":"0","DATA-block-D5e35a3db27fb4":"0#TRANSP <p style=\"text-align: center;\" data-mce-style=\"text-align: center;\"><span style=\"background-color: rgb(241, 196, 15); color: rgb(224, 62, 45);\" data-mce-style=\"background-color: #f1c40f; color: #e03e2d;\">This is some text<\/span><\/p>","DATA-block-K5e35a3f027fb5":"0#TRANSP20","DATA-block-C5e35a3f127fb6":"01#ffff000images\/250place.jpg\u00b8","DATA-block-F5e35a3fc27fb7":"121212undefined","DATA-block-G5e35a40327fb9":"01#TRANSP#TRANSP","DATA-block-H5e35a40c27fba":"01#TRANSP#64cc34#4aa121270#ffffff#ffffff040930001000000000000Open Sans:800\u00b8\u00b8CHECK THIS OUT NOW - CLICK HERE\u00b8","page_name":"Page ba","aff_link":"","pause_link":"","seo_title":"","fbook":"","seo_desc":"","seo_keywords":"","back_color":"#EEEEEE","body_color":"#FFFFFF","back_image":"","ty_font_color":"#000000","ty_override":"","ty_name":"1234","ty_stm":"","modal_para_width":"0","catcha_url":"","catcha_un":"Yes","catcha_message":"","code_head":"","code_body":"","modal_share_width":"0","modal_cta_width":"0","modal_video_width":"0","modal_mp_width":"0","modal_stm_width":"0","modal_image_width":"0","modal_bonus_width":"1","ty_headline":"","modal_spacer_width":"0","att_bar_status":"0","att_delay_in":"0","att_bar_color":"#bbbbbb","att_gradient":"0","att_text_color":"#000000","att_text_font":"Open Sans:400","att_text_size":"14","att_bar_message":"Add Your Attention Bar Text Here","att_link_color":"#000000","att_link_label":"Add Link Text Here","att_link_url":"http:\/\/commissiongorilla.com","count_font":"Open Sans:800","count_size":"55","count_status":"1","count_type":"0","count_end":"02\/01\/2020 9:14 PM","count_zone":"0.0","count_eg_days":"0","count_eg_hours":"0","count_eg_mins":"0","count_digit_color":"#bbbbbb","count_label_color":"#bbbbbb","count_background":"0","count_language":"1","count_exp":"1","count_url":"http:\/\/commissiongorilla.com","count_add_days":"0","count_add_hours":"0","count_add_mins":"0","modal_countdown_width":"0","modal_review_width":"0"}
```

all i want todo is sort the first object "sortlist"
i have tried to make it in array but it wont help. i want to manage it like:

```
D5e35a3db27fb4
K5e35a3f027fb5
C5e35a3f127fb6
F5e35a3fc27fb7
G5e35a40327fb9
```

How can i do this? Help is deeply appericiated.!

Comment: `$sortList = json_decode($sortListJson);
print_r(explode("block[]", $sortList->sortlist));`

Comment: @Ayaan check my answer, if its solved kindly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort json like below,

```
$jsonobj = '{"sortlist":"block[]=D5e35a3db27fb4&block[]=K5e35a3f027fb5&block[]=C5e35a3f127fb6&block[]=F5e35a3fc27fb7&block[]=G5e35a40327fb9&block[]=H5e35a40c27fba","save_cont_flag":"0","DATA-block-D5e35a3db27fb4":"0#TRANSP <p style=\"text-align: center;\" data-mce-style=\"text-align: center;\"><span style=\"background-color: rgb(241, 196, 15); color: rgb(224, 62, 45);\" data-mce-style=\"background-color: #f1c40f; color: #e03e2d;\">This is some text<\/span><\/p>","DATA-block-K5e35a3f027fb5":"0#TRANSP20","DATA-block-C5e35a3f127fb6":"01#ffff000images\/250place.jpg\u00b8","DATA-block-F5e35a3fc27fb7":"121212undefined","DATA-block-G5e35a40327fb9":"01#TRANSP#TRANSP","DATA-block-H5e35a40c27fba":"01#TRANSP#64cc34#4aa121270#ffffff#ffffff040930001000000000000Open Sans:800\u00b8\u00b8CHECK THIS OUT NOW - CLICK HERE\u00b8","page_name":"Page ba","aff_link":"","pause_link":"","seo_title":"","fbook":"","seo_desc":"","seo_keywords":"","back_color":"#EEEEEE","body_color":"#FFFFFF","back_image":"","ty_font_color":"#000000","ty_override":"","ty_name":"1234","ty_stm":"","modal_para_width":"0","catcha_url":"","catcha_un":"Yes","catcha_message":"","code_head":"","code_body":"","modal_share_width":"0","modal_cta_width":"0","modal_video_width":"0","modal_mp_width":"0","modal_stm_width":"0","modal_image_width":"0","modal_bonus_width":"1","ty_headline":"","modal_spacer_width":"0","att_bar_status":"0","att_delay_in":"0","att_bar_color":"#bbbbbb","att_gradient":"0","att_text_color":"#000000","att_text_font":"Open Sans:400","att_text_size":"14","att_bar_message":"Add Your Attention Bar Text Here","att_link_color":"#000000","att_link_label":"Add Link Text Here","att_link_url":"http:\/\/commissiongorilla.com","count_font":"Open Sans:800","count_size":"55","count_status":"1","count_type":"0","count_end":"02\/01\/2020 9:14 PM","count_zone":"0.0","count_eg_days":"0","count_eg_hours":"0","count_eg_mins":"0","count_digit_color":"#bbbbbb","count_label_color":"#bbbbbb","count_background":"0","count_language":"1","count_exp":"1","count_url":"http:\/\/commissiongorilla.com","count_add_days":"0","count_add_hours":"0","count_add_mins":"0","modal_countdown_width":"0","modal_review_width":"0"}';


$jsonarr = json_decode($jsonobj);

$sortlist = $jsonarr->sortlist;

$sortlist_exp = explode('&',$sortlist);

foreach($sortlist_exp as $item){
    $temp = explode('block[]=',$item);
    $finalArr[]= $temp[1];
}

var_dump($finalArr);
```

You can also do the foreach like below,

```
foreach($sortlist_exp as $item){
    $finalArr[] = str_replace("block[]=","",$item); 
}
```

**EDIT:**
As @Ayaan required the $finalArr in a single string, so he added like this

```
$final = implode("<br>", $finalArr); 
echo $final;
```

Thanks

Comment: edit : I have used implode function at the end. to make it like i asked in the question."$final = implode("<br>", $finalArr);
echo $final;"

Comment: @Ayaan you need the final in single string not in array?

Comment: Yes, in strings, so i can later equal them to data-blocks and then echo the value of data blocks.

Answer (score 0):

First you should json decode it, then use explode function to convert this text in sortlist to array, this is the solution to have array:

$object = json_decode($data);
$sortlist_array = explode("block[]=", $object['sortlist']);